# Iron palm monster hand training

Tags: training, kung-fu

[image]

How do you get a hand like this?
How do you achieve this goal?
Which exercises do I need to do for making my hand like this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you want a hand like this? Do you hate your hand? Did your hand do something bad, and now you have to punish it? Haha. No, seriously, if you do this to your hand to become more "powerful", 1) the "power" you get from this is useless without a delivery system (which requires pressure testing), and 2) your hand can become permanently damaged, even though the iron palm trainer gives you some special jow linament he says will prevent it (it won't). This is one of many martial arts concepts that should be abandoned.

Comment: I didn't hate my hand but I want to improve my power of my hand

Comment: Then find a good boxing instructor who can give you the tools needed to punch with power and to be able to land those punches on a resisting opponent. The type of training that results in damaging your hand is only going to hurt you. It's worse than useless. A good boxing gym will condition your hands to take impact, and will do so without the need for damaging your hands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [King of Iron Palm Training](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9334/king-of-iron-palm-training)

Answer (score -1):

This is abnormal iron palm. Hand should still appear soft and supple. Best method is internal method.  gradual striking of things with give. Slap river rocks. increase incrementally.Use a linament or blood moving exercise.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; it doesn't have enough detail.